# How to restrict users from editing certain fields in Reactive form kendo UI Angular?

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-reactive-forms, angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to restrict users from editing certain fields in a angular reactive form, I followed(copied) [this example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/#toc-basic-concepts) from the official docs, which do not say anything about **restricting** a specific field.Is there any work around for the same !
Thanks

Comment: You could disable the FormControls of the fields you don't want the user to edit.[Reference](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion do that will lead to not passing the data when the form is submitted, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through [this](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1576#issuecomment-393247689) and that made my day.